# Crear JsonResponse UTF-8 en Django

Tags: json, django, utf-8

¿Hay alguna forma simple de anular `DjangoJSONEncoder.ensure_ascii` y ponerlo en `False` o imprimir texto diferente de ascii en `django.http.JsonResponse` de cualquier otra forma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si Ud tiende a usar el formato utf-8, en vez del JsonResponse() de Django use esta forma:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False),
content_type="application/json")
```

o esta forma:

```
return JsonResponse(json.dumps(response_data, ensure_ascii=False),
safe=False)
```

Más acerca del safe=False   [ver AQUÍ](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)